# Sitecore Name Lookup Value List - Multilpe Values per Key

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Specifically in sitecore, the column configuration is defined using a Name Lookup Value List, and I want to add a colour drop down along side it so it can be applied specifically to each column as set up by the configuration. This means for each key (column ID) I want the column config as a drop down and the colour as a drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom field that will allow to do this, you should:

1. Create `Column Specification` template
2. Add 2 fields to this template: Column and Colour
3. Create items using this new template for every column you need
4. Instead of selecting columns in your Name Lookup Value List, select `Column Specification` items.

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought, I was hoping there was a more elegant solution without having to create lots of items.